# rps function not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Rps game code isn't working. My battle function is supposed to set win to a 1,2, or 3 but it always stays at the default 0. I've checked the other values through the console, and they all seem to be working. here is my code.

```
function Player(number) {
this.number = number;
this.choice = 0;
}

var player1 = new Player(1);
var player2 = new Player(2);
var win = 0;

var battle = function() {
if (player1.choice === player2.choice) {
    win = 3;
} else if (player1.choice + 2 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 1){
    win = 2;
} else if (player1.choice + 1 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 1) {
    win = 1;
} else if (player1.choice + 1 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 2) {
    win = 1;
} else if (player1.choice - 1 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 2) {
    win = 2;
} else if (player1.choice - 1 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 3) {
    win = 2;
} else if (player1.choice - 2 === player2.choice && player1.choice === 3) {
    win = 1;
} else {
    alert ('someone pressed the wrong button')
}
}

var Reset = function () {
win = 0;
player1.choice = 0;
player2.choice = 0;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 81) {
        player1.choice = 1;
    } else if (event.which === 87){
        player1.choice = 2;
    } else if (event.which === 69){
        player1.choice = 3;
    } else if (event.which === 37){
        player2.choice = 1;
    } else if (event.which === 40){
        player2.choice = 2;
    } else if (event.which === 39){
        player2.choice = 3;
    } 
})
if (player1.choice > 0 && player2.choice > 0) {
    battle();
    if (win === 1) {
        $('.winner').append('<p>player1 wins!</p>')
    } else if (win === 2) {
        $('.winner').append('<p>player2 wins!</p>')
    } else if (win === 3) {
        $('.winner').append('<p>It is a draw!</p>')
    }
}

})
```

My html has the div with class 'winner' in it.
**Additional question**
How do I cancel the keydown function after both players have chosen their options.

Comment: That's because the battle function is never called. This is easy to see if you add a console.log() to the battle() function. Something like `console.log('battling!')`. 

The check to see if both players have made a choice only occurs once when the document is first ready. This happens at a time when it would be unlikely that both players have had enough time to make their selections so the condition isn't met and battle() is never called. You'll need to set up some kind of loop to continuously run and check if both players have made selections.

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving your player a choice in the Player class you created? It should look like this:

```
function Player(number, choice) {
this.number = number;
this.choice = choice;
}
```